# How to split the CSV file among multiple users & Salve machines for Distributed testing In JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

How to split the CSV file among multiple users & Salve machines for Distributed testing In JMeter. My CSV file has 10,000 rows of test data and we want to share it among 400 users b/w Master machine and 8 slave machines.

How can I achieve the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the operating system you're using:

For Windows you can go for the [following](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-split-csv-file-into-multiple-files-using-powershell/) [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) script:

```
# variable used to store the path of the source CSV file
$sourceCSV = <path of source CSV> ;

# variable used to advance the number of the row from which the export starts
$startrow = 0 ;

# counter used in names of resulting CSV files
$counter = 1 ;

# setting the while loop to continue as long as the value of the $startrow variable is smaller than the number of rows in your source CSV file
while ($startrow -lt <total number of rows in source CSV>)
{

# import of however many rows you want the resulting CSV to contain starting from the $startrow position and export of the imported content to a new file
Import-CSV $sourceCSV | select-object -skip $startrow -first <number of rows in resulting CSV> | Export-CSV "<resulting CSV filepath>$($counter).csv" -NoClobber;

# advancing the number of the row from which the export starts
$startrow += <number of rows in resulting CSV> ;

# incrementing the $counter variable
$counter++ ;

}
```

For Unix and derivatives you can just use [split](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-command-in-linux-with-examples/) command

```
split -l 1250 file.csv splitted
```

Alternatively you can go for i.e. [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/), in this case you won't have to split the file and you will be able to load it on the one machine and make available to slaves via HTTP. HTTP Simple Table Server can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)